Spring Authorization Server: Authorized Scopes missing from token and from context.getAuthorizations()
I have a Spring Authorization Server 1.2.0 project where I have access to a RegisteredClient that has scopes profile and read.custom.scope. This client has grant types refresh_token and authorization_code. The authorizations are being persisted to the DB with appropriate repositories etc.
Up until recently I had no need for scopes in the token. When going to use them I realised the token doesn't have authorized scopes.
To remedy this I configured an OAuth2TokenCustomizer to add the consented scopes to the token as an authorities claim.
    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> oAuth2TokenCustomizer() {

        return context -> {
            OAuth2Authorization oAuth2Authorization = context.getAuthorization();

            context.getClaims().claim( "authorities", oAuth2Authorization.getAuthorizedScopes() );
        };
    }


However, this did not work as the oAuth2Authorization.getAuthorizedScopes() returns an empty Collection. I now see an empty array of authorities in the accessToken.
The persisted authorization entry also has an empty value for the accessTokenScopes property.
I'm able to debug the OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter and can see that the authentication object in the filter has the correct scopes I'd expect to see.
The big question: How can I ensure that the consented scopes become authorizedScopes that will be available when I call context.getAuthorizedScopes()?
Any and all pointers and help greatly welcome.

Embarrasingly, I had a bug in the code that converts the domain object to entity and the entity to the domain object.
For what it's worth. I was using accessToken.getToken().getScopes() to get the scopes and persist that, for some reason.
The correct place to get the scopes is of course from the authorization with authorization.getAuthorizedScopes()
Also, for what it's worth, the  OAuth2TokenCustomizer isn't needed to put the scopes into the token. That happens without this config, so that's not needed.
